# Can not catch NoProcessFoundForGivenName

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that closes all instances of MS Word where the file name opened in MS Word matches a pattern.  There are times when the Powershell script is invoked but there are no instances of MS Word running.
The cmdlet Get-Process is used to find MS Word and check the names of files that are currently open.

Nether the catch [NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand]   or
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand]   are getting caught.

```
{
   $MSWordProcessHandle = Get-Process WINWORD
} catch [NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand] {
   Write-Output "No instances of MS Word found running."
}
```

I keep getting the error below.

> ```
> Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "WINWORD". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.  
> At C:\Utils\scripts\Dev_Set_Close.ps1:24 char:27  
> +    $MSWordProcessHandle = Get-Process WINWORD  
> +                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (WINWORD:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException  
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
> ```

Comment: have you tried catching _everything_ [no type info with the `catch` call] and then examining what the caught type is in that scenario? plus, of course, you can add more than one `catch`  - they are processed in sequence and your last one can be the generic variety.

Comment: Even when everything is caught (no brackets "[", "]") the error is still thrown and the Write_Output is not performed.

Comment: i see that `Mike Shepard` pointed out the real problem ... great! i totally missed that very important point ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to use `-ErrorAction Stop` to force the non-terminating error to be an exception.

Then, When you can't figure out what specific exception to catch, Lee's suggestion to catch everything is helpful:

```
try {
   $MSWordProcessHandle = Get-Process WINWORD -ErrorAction Stop 
} catch {
  $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
}
```

This outputs `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException`

So, this is what you want:

```
try {
   $MSWordProcessHandle = Get-Process WINWORD -ErrorAction Stop 
} catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException]{
   Write-Output "No instances of MS Word found running."
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  The key was "First, you need to use -ErrorAction Stop to force the non-terminating error to be an exception."  I will have to research how to tell if a error is non-terminating.